# Filtering based on previous element in java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a specific condition whether i want to partition a list into two parts by comparing with previous element. situation is that there is a field called field1 and i need to group all elements into another list for which previous elements field1 is 0. i dont see any option in either collect or groupingBy/partitioningBy to provide a way to compare with previous element.

```
 private List<Class2> mapClasses(List<Class1> l1) {
        l1.sort(comparingInt(Class1::getField1());
        List<Class1> list1= new ArrayList<>();
        List<Class1> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0 && isOk(l1.get(0))) {
                consecutiveClasses.add(l1.get(0));
            } else if (i > 0 && isOk(l1.get(i - 1))) {
                consecutiveClasses.add(l1.get(i));
            } else {
                nonConsecutiveClasses.add(l1.get(i));
            }
        }

        List<Class2> collapsedClass2s = mapNonConsecutiveClasses(nonConsecutiveClass2s);
        mapConsecutiveClasses(consecutiveClasses).ifPresent(collapsedClasses::add);
        return collapsedClasses;
    }

    private boolean m2(Class1 current, Class1 previous) {
        return (current.isLocked() && previous.isLocked()) || (!current.isLocked() && !previous.isLocked());
    }
```

Is there a way I can do this with Java 8 streams?

Comment: Give us an example and expected result. It will help us give you a solution. I am not sure if you want to stop as soon as you see an element which has previous element with start time 0

Comment: Obvious approaches just disguise the for loop without really adding anything. If you wanted to do it in parallel, I think you might as well go straight for the fork-join framework with for loops.

Comment: Oh and, Guava apparently has zip, which you mind find useful to zip the list to itself truncated by an element.

Comment: from the list of orders, i just want to extract separate list whose previous element has startTime field set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

"from the list of objects, i just want to extract separate list whose previous element has field set to 0."
based on that

```
List<Object2> collect = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, objects.size()-1)
                .filter(i -> objects.get(i - 1).firld1== 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> objects.get(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```